# Extracting Lines of data from a string with RegEx

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have several strings, e.g.

```
(3)_(9)--(11).(FT-2)
(10)--(20).(10)/test--(99)
```

I am trying Regex.Match(here I do no know) to get a list like this:
First sample:

```
3
_
9
--
11
.
FT-1
```

Second Sample:

```
10
--
20
.
10
/test--
99
```

So there are several numbers in brackets and any text between them.
Can anyone help me doing this in vb.net? A given string returns this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `Split` method of `[String]`

```
"(3)_(9)--(11).(FT-2)".Split('()')
```

Another option is to match everything excluding `(` and `)`

As regex, this would do `[^()]+`

Breakdown

```
"[^()]" ' Match any single character NOT present in the list “()”
   "+"  ' Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

You can use following block of code to extract all matches

```
Try
    Dim RegexObj As New Regex("[^()]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim MatchResults As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
    While MatchResults.Success
        ' matched text: MatchResults.Value
        ' match start: MatchResults.Index
        ' match length: MatchResults.Length
        MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch()
    End While
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

Comment: Well, first I was surprised that string.split would work that way (even though it might have to be ....Split("()")  as ' is recognized as a comment? But the output was
"" (empty)
3)_
9)--
11).
FT-2)

The code block suppressed the first match (3), but I got the point and can investigate further. Thank you

Comment: @StefanMeyer - The split example is actually Powershell but it's using the .Net libraries to perform the split. I assumed syntax was kind of the same but there's some differences it seems *(my vb.net is none-existing)*

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Dim input As String = "(3)_(9)--(11).(FT-2)"
Dim searchPattern As String = "\((?<keep>[^)]+)\)|(?<=\))(?<keep>[^()]+)"
Dim replacementPattern As String = "${keep}" + Environment.NewLine
Dim output As String = RegEx.Replace(input, searchPattern, replacementPattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `Regex.Split` (formulated as a little console test):

```
Dim input = {"(3)_(9)--(11).(FT-2)", "(10)--(20).(10)/test--(99)"}
For Each s As String In input
    Dim parts = Regex.Split(s, "\(|\)")

    Console.WriteLine($"Input = {s}")
    For Each p As String In parts
        Console.WriteLine(p)
    Next
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

So basically we have a one-liner for the regex part.

The regular expression `\(|\)` means: split at `(` or `)` where the braces are escaped with `\` because of their special meaning within regex.

The slightly shorter regex `[()]` where the desired characters are enclosed in `[]` would produce the same result.